# how to extract data from an object that came from http.get response

Tags: json, angular, typescript, observable

I have an API that responds with the following object of type json :

```
 {
    "triggerCount": {
        "ignition_state_off": 16,
        "ignition_state_on": 14,
        "exit_an_area": 12,
        "enter_an_area": 19,
        "door_unlocked": 1,
        "door_locked": 1,
        "fuel_level_below": 12
    }
}
```

### I get the response through this injected service :

```
interface ITrigger{
  triggerCount: ITriggerCount;
}

interface ITriggerCount{
  [key:string]: number;
}


@Injectable()
export class DbApiService {

   private triggersUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/triggers';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  } 


getTriggerCount(){
  return this.http.get<ITrigger>(this.triggersUrl)
  }

}
```

### component where i inject the service:

```
export class TriggersComponent implements OnInit {


@Input() triggerCountChart = [];

triggers:any;
tempArray: any = [];

  constructor(private triggerService: DbApiService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getTriggerCount()
    this.buildChart()

  }


  getTriggerCount(){


  this.triggerService.getTriggerCount().subscribe(data =>{this.triggers = data;
    this.tempArray = this.triggers.triggerCount;
    console.log(this.triggers,this.tempArray);
        } );

}
```

As you see I console log the the response results, so I can see how it looks and it works, here is a screenshot of the console in my browser :

[image]

what I really want to do is extract attributes strings such as `ignition_state_off` and save them in an array of type string and extract their values and save them in an array of type numbers in order to use those arrays to render a chart.

### chart function

this chart currently uses data I have manually inserted as you can see in `trigglerlabels` array and `triggerCountArray` :

```
buildChart(){

  let triggerLabels = ['ignition_off','ignition_on','enter-area','exit-area','door_unlocked','door_locked','fuel_drop'];

  let triggerCountArray = [12,13,22,32,14,8,17]

  this.triggerCountChart = new Chart('canvas-triggers', {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
      labels: triggerLabels,
      datasets: [
        { 
          data: triggerCountArray,
         // borderColor: "#3cba9f",
          backgroundColor: ["#e8f1f2","#b9c0c1","#8d99ae","#3283a9","#006494","#283c4e"],
          fill: false
        },

      ]
    },
    options: {

      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'applets created in percentage',
        fontSize:14
    },
      legend: {
        display: true,
        position: "right",
        labels: {
          boxWidth : 40,
          fontSize : 14
        }
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          display: false
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          display: false
        }],
      }
    }
  });


}
```

I hope I was clear in explaining what is the issue here, I have looked in many places on-line with no luck, please help.

Comment: Are you just looking for `Object.keys( this.tempArray )` and `Object.values( this.tempArray )` (just be warned, they might not be necessarily in the same order ). Or do you just want `Object.keys( this.tempArray ).reduce( (current, item) => { current.labels.push( item ); current.values.push( this.tempArray[item] ); return current; }, { labels: [], values: [] } )`

Comment: yes i only want the keys (if by keys you mean labels such "ignition_state_off") and values. but it is important for me that they stay in order, otherwise how would i know each value to which label corrosponds? but will give this a try and see.

Comment: Then the one with reduce would be the easiest I believe

Comment: using this my arrays would be labels and values. how would i use them in my chart function(my chart function is within the same class) should i declare them in the class level? i tried to console.log(labels) but the editor complained that it cant find name labels

Comment: as i have declared the labels and values on the class level,  it worked which is greate. but the first element in both labels and values is not there, so i have 7 elements, but in labels and values there are 6 elements in each. where could be the problem ?

Comment: nevermind, that was because i removed the "{ labels: [], values: [] } " at the end after i declared them on the top. would still be nice if you can explain it though. your answer have answered my question, you can add it as an answer, so i can accept it. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as mentioned in the comments, you just need to extract the information to match your target data structure.

To do this, you can first extract the keys, and then restructure your data using

```
Object.keys( this.tempArray ).reduce( function( current, item ) {
  current.labels.push( item );
  current.values.Push( this.tempArray[item] );
  return current;
}, { labels: [], values: [] } );
```

Where [`Object.keys( this.tempArray )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) extract all the keys from an object into an array of strings, and then you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to loop over your data and keep the data you are interested in. The second parameter (if given) will give you your starting function, where as each next iteration will use the last returned value from your first parameter.